# Manipulating maps in Grails/jQuery from the client-side

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp

I have a Grails (2.3.6) controller that looks like this:

```
class WidgetController {
    def index() {
        Map<String, List<String>> widgetMap = getSomehow()
        render (
            view: "widgets",
            model: [ widgetMap: widgetMap ]
        )
    }
}
```

Let's say, at runtime, the `widgetMap` will be the equivalent of this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> widgetMap = []

List<String> colors = []
List<String> pets = []

colors << "Red"
colors << "Blue"
colors << "Green"

pets << "Dog"
pets << "Cat"

widgetMap.put("Colors", colors)
widgetMap.put("Pets", pets)
```

And the `widgets.gsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Omitting a bunch of stuff for brevity -->
</head>
<body>
    <g:select name="widgetMapSel" from="${widgetMap}" />
    <ul id="widgetList">
    </ul>

    <g:javascript>
        // Save the Grails-injected 'widgetMap' to JS.
        var widgetMap = ${widgetMap};

        $.("#widgetMapSel").on('change', function() {
            var select = this;
            var selectedOpt = select.value; // "Colors", "Pets", etc.

            // Query 'widgetMap' for key that matches the text inside the 'selectedOpt'
            var key = ???

            // Get list of values associated with key
            var list = widgetMap[key];      // ["Red", "Blue", "Green"] - OR - ["Dog", "Cat"], etc.

            // Clear the current 'widgetList' list.
            $.("#widgetList").empty();

            // Populate the 'widgetList' with our new list.
            $.each(...) {
                $.("#widgetList").append("<li>" + list[i] + "</li>);
            }
        });
    </g:javascript>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to store the `widgetMap` as a JS/jQuery variable, and then dynamically clear/populate `widgetList` from that variable, based on what selection the user has currently made. Hence if the user selects "Colors", they'll see a `<ul>` of the 3 colors. If they select "Pets", they'll see a `<ul>` of the 2 pets.

The code I have so far for this is just pseudo-code, and I can't quite seem to see the "forest through the trees". Any ideas as to what exact GSP/jQuery changes I need to make to get this to work?

---

**Please note:** I'm only interested in this (non-sclabale) solution, whereby the map/model is injected into a JS variable, one time, at page load.

Comment: Try ```var widgetMap = ${widgetMap as JSON};```.

Comment: Thanks @Ken - do I need to import `JSON` at the top of my GSP? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete answer:

```
// widgets.gsp
<%@ page import="grails.converters.JSON" expressionCodec="none" %>
// other gsp stuff
<g:javascript>
    var widgetMap = ${widgetMap as JSON};
```